# Flexiforce to Uno to Keyboard. Working but not as inteded

Tags: arduino-uno, mac-os, java

I have a Flexiforce 25 pound pressure sensors connected to my Arduino Uno which connects to my laptop. My requirement is to be able to play video games using taps on pressure sensors. I am successfully sending signals to my Laptop and I am using Java on my Mac to send keystrokes (Key Down and Key Up) signals to move in the game. However I am facing issues with long key down and key up. How do I detect that and make sure that my program runs smooth?

Uno code:

```
void setup() {}

void loop() {
int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);
int sensorValue3 = analogRead(A2);
int sensorValue4 = analogRead(A3);
int sensorValue5 = analogRead(A4);
int sensorValue6 = digitalRead(2);

// Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
float voltage2 = sensorValue2 * (5.0 / 1023.0);
float voltage3 = sensorValue3 * (5.0 / 1023.0);
float voltage4 = sensorValue4 * (5.0 / 1023.0);
float voltage5 = sensorValue5 * (5.0 / 1023.0);
float voltage6 = sensorValue6 * (5.0 / 1023.0);

if(voltage > 1){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("A0"); Serial.end();
}
if(voltage2 > 1){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("A1"); Serial.end();
}
if(voltage3 > 1){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("A2"); Serial.end();
}
if(voltage4 > 1){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("A3"); Serial.end();
}
if(voltage5 > 1){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("A4"); Serial.end();
}
if(voltage6 > 0){ 
   Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("D2"); Serial.end();
}
// Wait 100 milliseconds
delay(100);
}
```

In java I'm using `java.wt.Robot` and `gnu.io.SerialPort` to press key and read from serial port. On a serialEvent I will override the listener function to perform my operation which is press Keys on my machine.

Java Code:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            String inputLine = null;
            if (input.ready()) {
                inputLine = input.readLine();
                if (inputLine.contains("A0")) {

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                    }
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                    System.out.println("UP");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("A1")) {

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                    }
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                    System.out.println("DOWN");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("A2")) {

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                    }
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
                    System.out.println("LEFT");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("A3")) {

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
                    }
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
                    System.out.println("RIGHT");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("A4")) {

                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < duration) {
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                    }
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                    System.out.println("S");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("D2")) {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_D);
                    System.out.println("D");

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This performs Up, Down, Left, Right, "S" and "D" operation for SuperMario 3 GBA game. This works but not as smooth as intended. Is there anything that I can use to directly bind to my keyboard to get a smoother key operations.